# synchronize ADC conversion and measure it in a specific part of a internal pwm signal

Tags: c++, eclipse, arm, pwm, adc

I need read my AD inputs only in a specific part of a internal pwm signal. My pwm has a period of 1 ms and initial polarity=low. I know that's possible to synchronize the AD conversion with a internal signal, I want to measure just in the high level from pwm but I don't know how to execute the measure only in a specific part of the signal. I'm using MK22FX512VLH12 microcontroller and processor expert (kinetis design). can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Usually PWM peripherals allow the trigger of the ADC via a register. In the STM32F PWM peripherals one of the four Capture Compare Registers (CCR) are used as a trigger for ending sampling and starting conversion.

Usually though HAL drivers and configuration tools don't cover this use case. You will probably have to look at the datasheet for your micro to set the PWM and ADC peripherals appropriately. For your micro it looks like the "Channel trigger output" - "...provides a trigger signal that is used for on-chip modules."

Alternatively you can use a periodic timer that is synchronised to the PWM to trigger the ADC.